# vb.net: how do I retrieve the index of a combo box element when it has been edited?

Tags: excel, vb.net, combobox

Hi I'm using visual basic to code a program that will edit the contents of the database. The user can type in what they want to change and then the program will overwrite this in the database. This all works fine apart from when the contents of the combo box is edited. When I try to then retrieve the index of what has been edited in the combo box I get -1.

If this doesn't make sense then my code is below:

```
Sub DatabaseWriteSpecific(array, filePath, row)
        Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
        Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath) 'opens specified database
        objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For i As Integer = 1 To array.length
            objSheet.Cells(row, i).value = array(i - 1) 'adds each user input to database
        Next
        objWorkbook.Save() 'saves these changes
        objWorkbook.Close()
        objExcel.Quit()
    End Sub
    Private Sub editButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles editButton.Click
        Dim userMsg = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit this quote?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
        If userMsg = 6 Then 'if answer is yes then quote will be edited, else nothing happens
            Dim quote = quoteCombo.Text
            Dim inputBoxes = {quote, userAct.Text, userScene.Text, userTheme.Text, userSaidBy.Text, userSaidTo.Text}
            Dim row = quoteCombo.SelectedIndex() + 2
            testBox.Text = row
            DatabaseWriteSpecific(inputBoxes, "C:\Users\lauel\Documents\database\bankOfQuotes.xlsx", row)
            comboBoxDisplay()
            MessageBox.Show("Your quote has been edited.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem line is `Dim row = quoteCombo.SelectedIndex() + 2` If the combo box selection is edited, it returns -1 + 2. If any other box is edited it works fine. Is there a way to work round this, or would you recommend writing to the database a different way? Thanks, and sorry if I have explained this awfully.

Comment: Can you not just use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: @Jaxi sorry I'm not actually familiar with what that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an overview perspective it seems like to me that you are trying to use a combo box for two purposes, when IMHO it should be used for one purpose, the display of one or more values. The behavior of combo boxes that facilitate editing I think is only intended for a user to type in (and match on) one of the values available.

Your goal though is a plausible one. You want to provide a facility to edit those values available in the combo box. I believe the right thing to do is to separate the functionality. Place the selected value in an editable text box, provide a means to save the edited value (such as a 'save' button), then update the combo box with the new, updated list of values.

Comment: okay thank you for your suggestion, I'll just add in an extra text box below!